# Jekyll get position in array

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to find the position of an element in an array without creating a loop and a conditional inside the loop. I know that languages like java have a method to do this "indexOf" but I was wondering if Jekyll/liquid has something like this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Liquid doesn't seem to have such method.

Even though, it can be implemented with [Liquid filters](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#liquid-filters) and it will be possible to write it like that: `{{ myarray | indexOf: "value" }}`.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, I can't find any reference to indexOf filter, could you point me to documentation? Thanks again

Comment: Hello javiburon. indexOf does not exist by default in jekyll liquid. But it can be implemented as  a custom [liquid filter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#liquid-filters).